# How can I avoid repetitive values getting echoed

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to retrieve data from a database table that contains correct score odds of games but what I am getting is a repetitive echo of a bet market foreach of the resultant correct score odds. Please how can I get this result with each correct score grouped under their own market like HTCS or FTCS without repetition of the market on each correct score and also to make the resultant correct scores get displayed in a row instead of a column. Please checkout my code and pinpoint what I should do to make it work out.

```
if(isset($_POST['gem_id'])) {
    $query = 'SELECT correct_score.id, correct_score.lig_id, 
                    correct_score.fixt_id, correct_score.mark_id, 
                    correct_score.score, correct_score.odds, 
                    correct_score.last_update,
                    fixtures.lig, fixtures.home_team, fixtures.away_team, 
                    leagues.league, bet_markets.market
            FROM correct_score
                INNER JOIN fixtures ON correct_score.fixt_id = fixtures.id 
                INNER JOIN leagues ON correct_score.lig_id = leagues.id
                INNER JOIN bet_markets ON correct_score.mark_id = bet_markets.id 
            WHERE correct_score.fixt_id =? 
            ORDER BY correct_score.id ASC';

    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute([$_POST['gem_id']]);
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    if($result) {
        foreach ($result as $row) {
?>
            <p class="card-title text-center text-uppercase fw-bolder mt-3"><?=$row['market'];?></p>
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <p class="chose" market="<?=$row['mark_id'];?>" fixture="<?=$row['fixt_id'];?>" pick="<?=$row['score'];?>" odds="<?=$row['odds'];?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary " ><span class="text-start"><?=$row['score'];?> </span><span class="text-end ms-5"><?=$row['odds'];?></span></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php 
        }
    } else { 
?>
     <div class="col-12"></div>
<?php 
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Well to help we would need to know a bit more about your database

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired result of grouping correct scores under their respective markets and displaying them in a row instead of a column, you can modify your code as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['gem_id'])) {
$query = 'SELECT correct_score.mark_id, bet_markets.market, GROUP_CONCAT(correct_score.score) AS scores
          FROM correct_score
          INNER JOIN bet_markets ON correct_score.mark_id = bet_markets.id
          WHERE correct_score.fixt_id = ?
          GROUP BY correct_score.mark_id';
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute([$_POST['gem_id']]);
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
if($result) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {?>
        <p class="card-title text-center text-uppercase fw-bolder mt-3"><?=$row['market'];?></p>
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-12">
                <?php
                $scores = explode(',', $row['scores']);
                foreach ($scores as $score) {?>
                    <p class="chose" market="<?=$row['mark_id'];?>" fixture="<?=$row['fixt_id'];?>" pick="<?=$score;?>" odds="<?=$row['odds'];?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="text-start"><?=$score;?></span><span class="text-end ms-5"><?=$row['odds'];?></span></button></p>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }
} else { ?>
    <div class="col-12"></div>
<?php }
```

}

In the modified code, the SQL query uses the GROUP_CONCAT function to concatenate the correct scores for each market into a single column called scores. This way, you can retrieve all the correct scores for a specific market in a comma-separated string.

After fetching the results, the code uses the explode function to split the scores string into an array of individual scores. Then, within the nested foreach loop, each correct score is displayed as a button within a single col-12 column.

This modification ensures that the correct scores are grouped under their respective markets and displayed in a row, avoiding repetitive echoes of the bet market for each correct score.

Comment: This answer was far to quick! Are you working with 2 accounts?

Comment: no as you see the account which asked was created 40 days ago , mine was from over 1 year. Also as you can see this is the only question I answered for this account. Therefore I am a individual account and I don't know who Juma Ijesun is. But thanks for your concern :)

Comment: @Johi correct scores have been grouped as I wanted but they are in a column. The are not displayed in a row

Comment: @Johi its now okay. I just changed the <div class="col-12"> to <div class="col-3"> and put it immediateley after your php $scores explode code and before the <p> tag.

Comment: This answer is grouping correct scores correctly but odds are same for all correct scores. This is an error. @Johi please can you check your answer again?

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?